# Getting error as java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, bugzilla

I am getting the following error by running the below code using j2bugzilla a

```
Code:
  GetLegalValues get = new GetLegalValues(Fields.COMPONENT);
       try {
        connect.executeMethod(get);
    } catch (BugzillaException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to retrieve the fieldValue:"+e);
        }
       Set<String> values = get.getLegalValues();

       for(String value : values) {
           System.out.println("The value for given field:"+value);
       }
```

exception:

```
"main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.parser.XmlRpcResponseParser.addResult(XmlRpcResponseParser.java:61)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.parser.RecursiveTypeParserImpl.endValueTag(RecursiveTypeParserImpl.java:78)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.parser.XmlRpcResponseParser.endElement(XmlRpcResponseParser.java:186)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1741)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2898)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:186)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:156)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:69)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:137)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:126)
    at com.j2bugzilla.base.BugzillaConnector.executeMethod(BugzillaConnector.java:149)
    at Logging.LogginDefects1.fieldValue(LogginDefects1.java:235)
    at Logging.LoggingDefects.main(LoggingDefects.java:33)
```

source at LogginDefects1.java:235,this is the function to retrieve the field value form bugzilla
public void fieldValue()
   {

```
   GetLegalValues get = new GetLegalValues(Fields.COMPONENT);
  try {

    connect.executeMethod(get);
} catch (BugzillaException e) {
    System.out.println("Failed to retrieve the fieldValue:"+e);
    }
   Set<String> values = get.getLegalValues();

   for(String value : values) {
       System.out.println("The value for given field:"+value);
   }
```

}

Comment: Please show the complete exception, rather than just the message.

Comment: I added full exception details please check it and help me out

Comment: At this point it looks like it's a Bugzilla API bug. I would try to have a look at what the request/response look like. It's possible that it's an error response which isn't being parsed properly, in which case you might be able to work around it by fixing the request to avoid it creating an error.

Comment: If you have any idea about this,please share it.

Comment: Well I've already *given* you an idea - look at what request/response is being sent/received (e.g. with Wireshark or Fiddler).

Comment: What is on source line `LogginDefects1.java:235`? Which version of `j2bugzilla` are you using? Which version of `BugZilla` is running on the server you are connect to?

Comment: public void fieldValue()
   {
   GetLegalValues get = new GetLegalValues(Fields.COMPONENT);
   try {
     
  connect.executeMethod(get);
 } catch (BugzillaException e) {
  System.out.println("Failed to retrieve the fieldValue:"+e);
  }
    Set<String> values = get.getLegalValues();

    for(String value : values) {
        System.out.println("The value for given field:"+value);
    }
   }

Comment: This can't be one single line.

Comment: The source at LogginDefects.java:33

Comment: Bugzilla version-3.2.3                                                                                                J2bugzilla version-2.1.1